# how can i pass my ObservableCollection of any type to a method? c#

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

I have ObservableCollections and i want to perform binary search on them . i have the below code

```
            // BINARYSEARCH
            int min = 0;
            int max = ObservableCollectionofcustomtype.Count - 1;
            while (min <= max)
            {
                int middle = min + (max - min) / 2;
                if (ObservableCollectioncustomtype[middle].Id == id)
                {
                    //do something
                }
                else if (ObservableCollectioncustomtype[middle].Id < id)
                    min = middle + 1;
                else
                    max = middle - 1;
            } //ENDBINARYSEARCH
```

i want to create a method that i can call from anywhere pass it my ObservableCollection of any type and an int id and perform the above code on it. how can i do this? ObservableCollection dont have .BinarySearch method like lists. my problem is passing my ObservableCollection of any type.

Comment: What do you know so far, what *can* you do? Can you create a method available everywhere? Can you pass a collection view? An integer? Where *exactly* do you need help?

Comment: updated my question for clarification. basically i want to be able to pass my collectionView of any type to the method.

Comment: What happens when you pass a "CollectionView"?

Comment: basically i dont know how to convert this code into a method that i can call from anywhere. replaced CollevtionView with ObservableCollection because thats what i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

```
public static class ObservableCollectionExtensions
{
    public static int BinarySearch<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> ObservableCollectioncustomtype)
        where T: InterfaceWithPropertyId
    {         
        // BINARYSEARCH
        int min = 0;
        int max = ObservableCollectioncustomtype.Count - 1;
        while (min <= max)
        {
            int middle = min + (max - min) / 2;
            if (ObservableCollectioncustomtype[middle].Id == id)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else if (ObservableCollectioncustomtype[middle].Id < id)
                min = middle + 1;
            else
                max = middle - 1;
        } //ENDBINARYSEARCH
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain InterfaceWithPropertyId?

Comment: nevermind this worked for me. for future people who come here create an interface.     public interface interfacewithpropertyId
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    } and then have your custom classes inherit it

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this if you dont know what type of collection you have:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace SeeSharperTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ObservableCollection<string> myCollectionString = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            myCollectionString.Add("foo");
            BinarySearch(myCollectionString);


            ObservableCollection<int> myCollectionInt= new ObservableCollection<int>();
            myCollectionInt.Add(123);
            BinarySearch(myCollectionInt);
    }



    public static object[] BinarySearch(params object[] pArgs)
    {
        dynamic collection = pArgs[0];

        int min = 0;
        int max = collection.Count - 1;
        while (min <= max)
        {
            int middle = min + (max - min) / 2;
            if (collection[middle].Id == id) 
            {
                // Do something
                break;
            }
            else if (collection[middle].Id < id) 
                min = middle + 1;
            else
                max = middle - 1;
        }

        
        // Convert dynamic collection to object[]
        object[] result = new object[collection.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
        {
            result[i] = collection[i];
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```